# repetition of numbers, consecutive numbers- not allowed

Tags: numbers, repeat

I want to create a validator which should allow 3 digit and which should not allow same numbers, no repetition of numbers, no consecutive numbers. ex: 111, 123, 121 not allowed.

How to create a validator with combination of these conditions?

Comment: I am new to use regex and I dont know how to get a solution for this requirement. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are perfect to check the format of a string.

Comment: Ya, can you please provide a regular expression for this. Thanks